# Optimize floating-point calculations

Tags: c, floating-point

I have a task to make the following function as precise (the speed is not the aim) as possible. I *have to* use *float* and the *method of middle rectangles*. Could you suggest something? Actually, I think, it's all about minimization of float rounding errors. That's what I've done:

```
typedef float T;

T integrate(T left, T right, long N, T (*func)(T)) {
    long i = 0;
    T result = 0.0;
    T interval = right - left;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        result += func(left + interval * (i + 0.5) / N) * interval / N;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `result += func(left + interval * (i + 0.5) / N) * interval` and `return result / N;`

Comment: Is that function pointer call necessary? Can it be inlined?

Comment: @Mysticial yes, it's necessary. But I don't need speed, I need precision, so that's okay.

Comment: Oops... for some reason, I misread your question as making it as fast as possible.

Comment: "I have to use float and the method of middle rectangles." - That sounds like a very arbitrary restriction. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Is `func` argument arbitrary, or something is known about it?

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk It's something like sin(x), or x, for example. Something not very curvy.

Comment: @o2genum Your function looks like rectangle method for getting integral. According to the Wiki page the accuracy grows with increasing number of Ns (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method). So just multiply N by two for the number of iterations :)

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk There are two sources of error: (1) the difference between the sum of the areas of the rectangles and the area under the curve (2) floating point rounding error. As N increases, the first source of error decreases, but the second increases because there are more calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could avoid or compensate for floating-point rounding (MM's suggestion, using Kahan summation, etc...).  However, there's no reason to do so, because the rounding errors are *absolutely dwarfed* by the error of the integration scheme; you won't get a more accurate integral, you'll get a more accurate approximation of the incorrect result computed by the midpoint rule.  Any such effort is entirely wasted except in extremely specialized circumstances.

Comment: For N = 18823 relative error is -1,78814E-07 (integrating sin(x) from 0 to Pi). If I change T to double, it's 1,16068E-09. The difference is not great, yes.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a task to make the following function as precise as possible

You say that you have to use `float`, so I assume the question isn't about rounding, but rather about computing the integral more accurately.

I also assume that simply increasing `N` is not an option.

Instead of using the mid-point rule, my suggestion is to consider using a [higher-order quadrature rule (trapezoid, Simpson's etc)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Quadrature_rules_based_on_interpolating_functions).

Comment: Exactly right.  For almost any choice of `func`, the error due to the integration scheme dominates the error due to floating-point rounding.  The only way to significantly improve accuracy is to use a more sophisticated integrator.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I edited question: I have to use the method of middle rectangles. So everything is about floats. How can I recombine them, add, multiply, etc. to make calculations more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{
   long i = 0;
   T result = 0.0;
   T interval = right - left;
   for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       result += func(left + interval * (i + 0.5) / N);
   }
   return result * interval / N;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help or helped very little.

Comment: It is he best you can get, IMO. It is the only thing that can be optimized for accuracy (and perhaps the calcuation of the index, i.e. the i + 0.5 part -- you could use a while loop and increment a float instead of the integer value. But you can't expect too much accuracy with 32 bit floats.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compute an integral precisely, go read up on integration schemes. Some home-knit routine won't give any kind of precision

The book ["Numerical recipes"](http://www.nr.com) (there are several versions, one for C) is highly regarded. Haven't looked at it personally.